# Imager plugin doesn't generate images in multi-language website

Tags: localization, plugin-imager

I upgraded a website from a single to multi-locale site and found out that the images (generated with the Imager plug-in) won't load in the new locale; I get a 404 for every image that the browser tries to load. However, the images do load in the new locale when the entry has been loaded in the original locale first.

It seems that Imager only generates the images when they're requested in the websites original locale; does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your image field set as translatable?

Comment: @Jan_dh No, all asset fields are set globally.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: `imagerSystemPath` was set relatively

Answer (score 1):

You might get more help creating an issue on the plugin Author's GitHub Repo here: https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft